# How can I add two each row sum depending on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, sum

So, I'm trying to add two to each row sum depending on whether or not the button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="prof" name="prof" value="0">
<input class="mod" name="mod" type="text" value='2'>
<input class="savings" name="savings" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="prof" name="prof" value="0">
<input class="mod" name="mod" type="text" value='4'>
<input class="savings" name="savings" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
//when document is ready, have numbers appear in each '.savings'
$(document).ready(function() {
//on button click, change the number depending on if checked or not
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('tr').each(function() {
        var sum = 2
        $(this).find('.mod').each(function() {
          var mod = $(this).val();
          if (!isNaN(mod) && mod.length !== 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(mod);
          }
        });
        $('.savings', this).val(sum);
      })
    } else {
      $('tr').each(function() {
        var sum = 0
        $(this).find('.mod').each(function() {
          var mod = $(this).val();
          if (!isNaN(mod) && mod.length !== 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(mod);
          }
        });
        $('.savings', this).val(sum);
      })
    }
  })
});
```

My problem is that the button click adds two to every row and not the row it's sitting in.
Any help would be appreciated.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sheepishlamb/3p9gary8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  var mod = $(this).next('.mod').val();
  var sum = ($(this).is(":checked")) ? 2 : 0;
  if (!isNaN(mod) && mod.length !== 0) {
    sum += parseFloat(mod);
  }
  $(this).siblings('.savings').val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="prof" name="prof" value="0">
      <input class="mod" name="mod" type="text" value='2'>
      <input class="savings" name="savings" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="prof" name="prof" value="0">
      <input class="mod" name="mod" type="text" value='4'>
      <input class="savings" name="savings" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the main issues I can see are that you're applying your function to all checkboxes.

`this` in your click function will refer to the checkbox you've clicked.

You just need to look at the `mod` and `savings` elements relative to the checkbox, so to search for the elements you need the parent element of the checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//on button click, change the number depending on if checked or not
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        var sum = 2
        $(this.parentElement).find('.mod').each(function() {
          var mod = $(this).val();
          if (!isNaN(mod) && mod.length !== 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(mod);
          }
        });
        $('.savings', this.parentElement).val(sum);
    } else {
        var sum = 0
        $(this.parentElement).find('.mod').each(function() {
          var mod = $(this).val();
          if (!isNaN(mod) && mod.length !== 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(mod);
          }
        });
        $('.savings', this.parentElement).val(sum);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="prof" name="prof" value="0">
<input class="mod" name="mod" type="text" value='2'>
<input class="savings" name="savings" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="prof" name="prof" value="0">
<input class="mod" name="mod" type="text" value='4'>
<input class="savings" name="savings" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```